# HP EliteBook 840 G6 Sound is not recognized only dummy device

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

Tried every trick on google, nothing works.
Seeing dummy devices and when doing alsa reload I get a kernel panic of a complete freeze.
Funny enough sound only works with USB headphones or USB-C not 3.5 mm or speakers in device.

Ubuntu 18.04.03 LTS
Alsa Info:
http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=4b41b6...26a146b6b23669

Comment: Same issue on Archlinux after last update of the kernel linux-lts

Answer (score 3):

Due to; https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem-osp1/+bug/1864061

```
echo "options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

sudo reboot
```

Comment: Please refrain from posting "solution only answers". Attempt to elaborate on not just the how, but the **why**.

Comment: trust me if I only knew why I would say, it seems like some driver is not loaded, I can never say why for sure.

Comment: Should it not be `snd_hda_intel` isntead of `snd-hda-intel`?